# Grouping Output by 2 id's

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a question.I have 3 tables like shown below :

Table company

```
 id_comp     comp_name       
     1        company1       
     2        company2                
     3        company3                
     4        company4
```

Table main

```
 id_main     code       description     id_comp
     1        100        Project 1         1
     2        200        Project 2         1
     3        300        Project 3         2
     4        400        Project 4         3
```

Table sub_main

```
id_sub_main     sub_code    sub_description   id_main
       1        101            Project 1.1      1
       2        102            Project 1.2      1
       3        201            Project 2.1      2
       4        202            Project 2.2      2
       5        203            Project 2.3      2
       6        401            Project 4.1      4
       7        402            Project 4.2      4
```

The question : what is the best mysql or php code to produce a table like shows below :

```
company    code    description    sub_code       sub_description
company1   100       Project 1      101            Project 1.1
                                    102            Project 1.2
           200       Project 2      201            Project 2.1
                                    202            Project 2.2
                                    203            Project 2.3
company3   400       Project 4      401            Project 4.1
                                    402            Project 4.2
```

The answer that I got mixed with Neels code :

```
company    code    description    sub_code       sub_description
1           100       Project 1      101            Project 1.1
1                                    102            Project 1.2
1           200       Project 2      201            Project 2.1
1                                    202            Project 2.2
1                                    203            Project 2.3
3           400       Project 4      401            Project 4.1
                                     402            Project 4.2
```

Comment: is id_main is foreign key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `MySQL` query:

```
SELECT company.comp_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(jointable.code ORDER BY jointable.code SEPARATOR '\n') as code,
GROUP_CONCAT(jointable.description ORDER BY jointable.code SEPARATOR '\n') as description,
GROUP_CONCAT(jointable.sub_code ORDER BY jointable.code SEPARATOR '\n') as sub_code,
GROUP_CONCAT(jointable.sub_description ORDER BY jointable.code SEPARATOR '\n') as sub_description
FROM
(SELECT main.id_comp,
main.code,
main.description,
GROUP_CONCAT(sub_main.sub_code ORDER BY sub_main.sub_code SEPARATOR '\n') as sub_code,
GROUP_CONCAT(sub_main.sub_description ORDER BY sub_main.sub_code SEPARATOR '\n') as sub_description
FROM main
INNER JOIN sub_main ON main.id_main = sub_main.id_main
GROUP BY main.id_main) jointable
INNER JOIN company ON company.id_comp = jointable.id_comp
GROUP BY company.id_comp;
```

See a Working SQL Fiddle here:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84e7b/10

Comment: tq Neels.problem solved with your code. I have edited my question. Tried to play around, but did not get as i wish. Hopefully you can help me

Comment: Check the edited code. I have modified the query again to suit your requirement. Hope this is final. :)

Comment: great @Neels really amazing

Comment: thank you very much @Neels . Dunno how to say a very much thanks to you. may God Bless you. tremendous code i ever learnt. Thanks again. Hopefully,will get lesson from you again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.code, a.description, b.sub_code, b.sub_description from main as a, sub_main as b where a.id_main = b.id_main group by a.code
```